# JBoss connecting to SQL Server: Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints

Tags: jdbc, sql-server-2012, certificate, jboss7.x

I am trying to fix a JBoss re-installation that needs to connect to SQL Server via JDBC and I'm seeing the following in the logs:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints
...
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints
...
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Algorithm constraints check failed on keysize limits: RSA 1024 bit key used with certificate: CN=SSL_Self_Signed_Fallback
```

How do I fix this?

From various configuration files on the server I have found security information in the configurations, such as:

```
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, SHA1 jdkCA & usage TLSServer, \
    RSA keySize < 1024, DSA keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, \
    include jdk.disabled.namedCurves

jdk.security.legacyAlgorithms=SHA1, \
    RSA keySize < 2048, DSA keySize < 2048

jdk.jar.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, RSA keySize < 1024, \
    DSA keySize < 1024, include jdk.disabled.namedCurves

jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, \
    DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, \
    include jdk.disabled.namedCurves
```

A number of posts relating to this issue claim this is an OpenJDK problem and to use another JDK or a JDBC problem and to use JTDS, but I believe the working server is using the same OpenJDK version and SQL Server JDBC driver. So, those approaches seem coincidentally addressing the issue. I tried copying the two java.security files from the working server to the one failing (per post 62582542), but that did not solve the issue.

Do I need to make a new 1024-bit, self-signed certificate?  Can I copy a certificate from our other, working server?  If I need to make a new certificate, what web page has the appropriate process?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a stronger certificate because RSA 1024bit certificates are considered too weak!

As a workaround, you can set the system property java.security.disableSystemPropertiesFile to **true**:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.disableSystemPropertiesFile=true
```

Also, set the security property security.useSystemPropertiesFile to **false** in `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security`

Answer (score 0):

A few things were done, which may be a superset of what is needed, to fix this.

1. The java.security file was modified to not allow other files to be appended to it or to append it.
2. All the 2048 bit references for protocols were changed to 1024.
3. I rebooted RHEL and then started JBoss - as opposed to simply rebooting bos